# python class default value inheritance

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I did some test today:

```
class SuperC():
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d='D0'):
        self.A = a
        self.B = b
        self.C = c
        self.D = d
        self.E = 'E0'

sup = SuperC('A0', 'B0', 'C0')
print(sup.A)  # >>> A0
print(sup.B)  # >>> B0
print(sup.C)  # >>> C0
print(sup.D)  # >>> D0
print(sup.E)  # >>> E0
```

you can see in the superclass, there are two types of default value (`d` and `e`)
`d` is more 'open', while `e` is kind of 'hidden'

Now, if I create a subclass, with a new attribute 'f':

```
class SubC1(SuperC):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, f):
        super().__init__(a, b, c)
        self.F = f

sub1 = SubC1('A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'F1')
print(sub1.A)  # >>> A1 
print(sub1.B)  # >>> B1
print(sub1.C)  # >>> C1
print(sub1.D)  # >>> D0
print(sub1.E)  # >>> E0  
print(sub1.F)  # >>> F1
```

I can see that `a`,`b`,`c` got good inheritance, and can accept new values.
But I did not choose to have `d` and `e` in `super().__init__()`. BUT they got perfect inheritance as well, and the problem is that I can not change the value of `d` and `e` while creating the instance of the subclass. and `f` works fine.

Now I create another subclass:

```
class SubC2(SuperC):
        def __init__(self, a, b, c, f, d='D2'): 
            super().__init__(a, b, c, d)  
            self.F = f

sub2 = SubC2('A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'F2')
print(sub2.A)  # >>> A2
print(sub2.B)  # >>> B2
print(sub2.C)  # >>> C2
print(sub2.D)  # >>> D2     
print(sub2.E)  # >>> E0  # hidden e is still E0
print(sub2.F)  # >>> F2
```

with `d` written in both `__init__()` and `super().__init__()`, now that d can get perfect inheritance and can be overwritten with new default value or new value in an new instance. but `e` will still be E0

It seems like the only good way is:

```
class SubC3(SuperC):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, f, d='new D', e='new E'):
        super().__init__(a, b, c)
        self.D = d  # set new
        self.E = e  # set new
        self.F = f

sub3 = SubC3('A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'F3')
print(sub3.A)  # >>> A3
print(sub3.B)  # >>> B3
print(sub3.C)  # >>> C3
print(sub3.D)  # >>> new D
print(sub3.E)  # >>> new E
print(sub3.F)  # >>> F3
```

Now that I can have both `d` and `e` with brand new default value/instance value, but if left non-indicated, then they will not inherit from the SuperC

**My question is, am I thinking this the right way?
Did I miss anything?
Are there better ways to set default value inheritance?**

**Or maybe in a way, that `e` is not supposed to be changed if written in this way? because it could be a fundamental attribute that is supposed to be a constant value for both superclass and subclass?**

Comment: This question ought probably be closed as entirely opinion based.  There is no "right" or "best" way to do this.  There's nothing "_wrong_" with any of your example classes.  Which you use just boils down to how you want to interact with your class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to fail the understand the issue...

When you do this:

```
class SuperC():
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d='D0'):
        self.A = a
        self.B = b
        self.C = c
        self.D = d
        self.E = 'E0'
```

`self.E` is not "hidden". It just received a hardcoded value: the string `"E0"` and `d='D0'` can be read as *If you're called with an specific value in the `d` argument, use that one, otherwise, just use the string `"D0"`* (it's a [named optional argument](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/optional_arguments.html))

When you do this:

```
class SubC3(SuperC):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, f, d='new D', e='new E'):
        super().__init__(a, b, c)
        self.D = d  # set new
        self.E = e  # set new
        self.F = f
```

What's happening is that the call to `super().__init__` creates a class with whatever `a, b, c` arguments you passed, a `self.E` and the hardcoded `"E0"`. After that, you do `self.E = e` and then you overwrite that `"E0"` with the value of the argument `e`.

Try this:

```
class SubC3(SuperC):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, f, d='new D', e='new E'):
        super().__init__(a, b, c)
        print("Before overwrite=%s" % self.E)
        self.D = d  # set new
        self.E = e  # set new
        print("After overwrite=%s" % self.E)
        self.F = f

sub3 = SubC3('A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'F3')
```

You'll see that right after the init, you see `self.E` being `"E0"` and then it's overwritten:

```
Before overwrite=E0
After overwrite=new E
```

About the `d`:

Try this:

```
class SubC3(SuperC):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, f, d='new D', e='new E'):
        super().__init__(a, b, c)
        self.E = e  # set new
        self.F = f

sub3 = SubC3('A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'F3')
print(sub3.D)
```

You'll see that it's `D0`, because you didn't pass any `d` to the super and you didn't overwrite it in `SubC3.__init__`, so it used the default in the `SuperC.__init__` (where you do `d='D0'`)

Comment: I understand what you said and how `d` and `e` got passed. I am actually asking, what is the best way to pass the attributes from superclass to subclass, if a default value was given in the superclass.

Comment: You mean what to do with the `d=...` since they're both defined in `SubC3` and `SuperC`?

Comment: I feel like there's no canonical way... To me, it all depends on the actual structure, and what _feels_ natural. If you have a base class that you wanna subclass, and in some subclasses you think you need an argument, but in other subclasses you won't need it, then a kwarg (the `d="D0"`) works fine. Otherwise, if all your subclasses are going to need the argument, then don't make it optional... I'd say it _depends_ on your actual scenario.