# Default values in class inheritance

Tags: python

I came across this code from Azure Python SDK

```py
class BlobConverter(meta.InConverter,
                    meta.OutConverter,
                    binding='blob',
                    trigger='blobTrigger'):
    @classmethod
    def check_input_type_annotation(cls, pytype: type) -> bool:
        return issubclass(pytype, (azf_abc.InputStream, bytes, str))
...
```

What does it mean that `binding` and `trigger` have default values assigned? I thought that space was used for defining [inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance).

Note that this is different from questions like [python-class-default-value-inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48039361/python-class-default-value-inheritance), where they discuss default values in the `__init__`-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These arguments get passed top the metaclass machinery during the class creation process. You should read about the details [here in the data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses).

In brief,

> By default, classes are constructed using type(). The class body is
> executed in a new namespace and the class name is bound locally to the
> result of type(name, bases, namespace).
>
> The class creation process can be customized by passing the metaclass
> keyword argument in the class definition line, or by inheriting from
> an existing class that included such an argument. In the following
> example, both MyClass and MySubclass are instances of Meta:
>
> ```
> class Meta(type):
>     pass
>
> class MyClass(metaclass=Meta):
>     pass
>
> class MySubclass(MyClass):
>     pass
> ```
>
> Any other keyword arguments that are specified in the class definition
> are passed through to all metaclass operations described below.

So, more concretely, this will be passed to:

```
namespace = metaclass.__prepare__(name, bases, **kwds)
```

When the namespace is prepared, where `**kwds` come from the class definition statement (excluding `metaclass`).

And, it also gets passed to the metaclass itself when constructing the class object:

```
metaclass(name, bases, namespace, **kwds)
```

And also, it will get passed to the parent class's `__init_subclass__`, but as the [docs note](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__), the default implementation `object.__init_subclass__` does nothing, but raises an error if it is called with any arguments.